C# how to implement treeview_getitemrect for treeview node's bounding rectangle
The goal is to move the cursor to the selected treeview item's bounding box for sending left or right mouse clicks.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvm-getitemrect <- this is the link I found on this issue.
The closest I could get is in the code below. But the return result is 0 still.
The nodeHandle is actually confirmed with the TVM_SELECTITEM sendmessage, I can see the selection happening.
Any insights or troubleshooting technique is welcome. Thank you.

        public const int TV_FIRST = 0x1100;
        public const int TVM_EXPAND = TV_FIRST + 2;
        public const int TVM_GETITEMRECT = TV_FIRST + 4;
        public const int TVM_SETITEM = TV_FIRST + 13;

        public const int TVM_GETNEXTITEM = TV_FIRST + 10;
        public const int TVM_SELECTITEM = TV_FIRST + 11;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct TREEVIEWRECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

public unsafe TREEVIEWRECT GetTreeNodeRect(IntPtr nodeHandle)
        {
            TREEVIEWRECT rc = new TREEVIEWRECT();

            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(rc));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, ptr, false);

            //approach 1
            //var intVal = nodeHandle.ToInt32();
            //var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intVal);

            //for(int i = 0;i < bytes.Length; i++)
            //{
            //    Marshal.WriteByte(ptr, i, bytes[i]);
            //}

            //approach 2
            IntPtr* ptr_loc = &nodeHandle;
            ptr = (IntPtr)ptr_loc;

            //apporach 3
            //ptr = nodeHandle;
           

            // Send the TVM_GETITEMRECT message
            var result = SendMessage(m_hWnd, TVM_GETITEMRECT, new IntPtr(1), ptr);

            var rect = Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(TREEVIEWRECT));

            if (result != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return rc;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to get item rectangle.");
            }
        }


Pointer to a RECT structure that, when sending the message, contains the handle of the item to retrieve the rectangle for.
I want to understand this better. These are the code changes I  have tried.
            //approach 1
            //var intVal = nodeHandle.ToInt32();
            //var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intVal);

            //for(int i = 0;i < bytes.Length; i++)
            //{
            //    Marshal.WriteByte(ptr, i, bytes[i]);
            //}

            //approach 2
            IntPtr* ptr_loc = &nodeHandle;
            ptr = (IntPtr)ptr_loc;

            //apporach 3
            //ptr = nodeHandle;

I have tried a similar code that is a modified version of the sample code shared here. But no luck still
SendMessage TreeView TVM_GETITEM crashes that process
